# Angular 4 with Bootstrap - LESS/SASS

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, less

I am working with bootstrap in Angular.

As we have css files alongside every component in Angular I am wondering what part SASS/LESS play. E.g. would I be swimming against the tide if I tried to implement to incorporate LESS/SASS into my angular application?

Comment: Not at all, if you are using angular cli, it has built in css processors to transpile less/sass. For example, in my project I am using bootstrap 3 css + my custom less

Comment: Not sure if this work out of the box, but I renamed some files from css to scss because I wanted some "inheritance" in some components and they kept working without touching anything else. EDIT: @LLai confirmed it is built-in if you are using ng cli :)

Comment: Absolutely not, using SASS/LESS in your application is a great idea. You just need to set up a process to compile and output your SASS/LESS files. I would recommend gulp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a good idea to use sass or less.  In factor Agnular CLI supports it. 
 If you're using Angular CLI, you can tell it to use sass instead of css. Here is an article from scotch.io (one of my favorites) on using sass with Angular CLI.  In general, to get started with an Angular application that uses sass, use the following command.

`ng new my-app --style=scss`

If you want to update your existing css application, you can run the following command to update the default.

`ng set defaults.styleExt scss`

From, there, you will need to update the names of your .css files to .scss.  Then you should be good.